# communication between two Android devices via OTG USB cable

Tags: android, usb, accessory, usb-otg

I'm trying to connect two Android devices with API 15+ via USB OTG cable.

Right now, I have one side "USB Host" based on this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Now I'm trying to connect to host from second Android Device.
I tried with this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

But unfortunately, although I have accessory_filter like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-accessory />
</resources>
```

both:

```
mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
```

return nulls on "not-host" endpoint of communication.
Battery is loading, popup with "USB computer connection" is shown.

Does anybody know how to handle this?

Comment: I still cannot solve this issue... Is it possible to communicate between two Android devices via ADB and sockets?

Comment: Problem resolved:
I had to force accessory mode in device from host, by sending special controlTransfer messages.

Comment: can you give some more details?

Comment: Everything You need is here :)
https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/apps/cts-usb-accessory/cts-usb-accessory.c?repo=platform--cts&r=62cd9f5c10470150d5b96f4f555c539a2a670713

Comment: You need this part after
`printf("Found possible Android device (%x:%x) " "- attempting to switch to accessory mode...\n", vendorId, productId);`

Comment: here is a demo app showing how it works https://github.com/quandoo/android2android-accessory

Comment: @ligi the link is broken, can you please point me to a working version?

Comment: Mariran @ligi I'm working on similar project, the link you shared is broken do you have link to demo or any details on how did you got it working?

Comment: https://github.com/manishsharma004/android2android-accessory